# inorder traversal in BST

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

**how to keep track of previous node in recursive inorder binary search tree traversal?**

eq...
in finding floor of any no... in bst ...iam trying to find the first number in bst which larger than given value ...and at that point printing the data of prev node which is either equal to or less then given value as it is inorder traversal...

> so why question is how  we can keep track of previous node in bst in
>   recursive inorder traversal??

Comment: Why *do* you need to keep track of the previous node in a recursive inorder traversal?

Comment: my task is to find floor ... i.e if 1,4,7,9,14,16 is in inorder than floor of 12 is 9... so i am finding first no. which is larger than given value which is 14 here...so answer will we 9 i.e previous node in inorder...so i want to ask how can we keep track of previous node...

Answer (score 1):

Binary tree recursion works by going down the left tree and then the right. Inorder/preorder/postorder are a convention that is determined merely by the ordering of some local action in the recursive procedure: the timing of the "visiting" of the current node itself with regard to the two recursive calls.

How you can get the next node is to have the recursion return it.

When you recurse into a tree, the last node visited in "inorder" is simply the rightmost node! Therefore, your recursion must simply return the rightmost node.

Furthermore, if a tree T as a whole has some previous node P, then the left subtree of T, namely left(T) also has the same previous node P. P is the predecessor of the leftmost node of T.

Moreover, the previous node with respect to right(T) is the node T itself.

So when recursing into left(T) we can simply pass down the same predecessor that was given to us, and when recursing into right(T) we pass ourselves as the predecessor.

Pseudocode:

```
# a recursive function that is given its previous node,
# and returns the rightmost node

recurse_with_previous (tree previous-in):
   # skip empty link. No leaf to see here!
   # previous-in is the rightmost node still
   if null(tree)
      return previous-in

   # if we are at a leaf, then that leaf is rightmost
   if leaf(tree)
      print "visiting leaf node " tree " with previous node " previous-in
      return tree

   # the previous node (previous-in) of this tree is actually the left
   # subtrees previous node, so we just pass that parameter down
   previous = recurse_with_previous (left(tree) previous-in)

   # inorder visit: visit this node between the subtrees
   print "visiting " tree " with previous node " previous

   # now the right subtree. what is ITS previous? Why, we are!!!
   # we return whatever this returns causing the return value
   # to be the rightmost node.
   return recurse_with_previous (right(tree) tree)

 # how to call
 recurse_with_previous(some-tree nil)
```

Comment: I love this site. Invent a pseudo-code language and it gets syntax highlighting on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

(Aside: It doesn't sound like you're asking for an in-order traversal, but rather a binary search function that returns the greatest node that is no greater than the query.)

The two most common ways of keeping track of stuff like this in a recursive algorithm are to either pass it down as a parameter, or to return back up to it. (Either way you're storing information about the past on the stack.)

In your case it's probably cleanest to do the latter. eg:

```
Node* floor_node(int x, Node *subtree) {
  if (subtree) {
    if(subtree->value > x) {
      return floor_node(x, subtree->left);
    } else {
      return floor_node(x, subtree->right) || subtree;
    }
  } else {
      return subtree;
  }
}
```